# Private window in Firefox dose not clear the cookies

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

I expect from a private window to delete cookies when I close that window but 
I noticed that it doesn't do that in this case: When you open a private window from another private window, you can still access to the cookies which have been set using the first private window.
For example If I visit example.com in a private window and then open another private window from that private window and close the first private window, cookies are still available in the second private window.

Is there  any convincing reason for that?

Comment: My guess is that there's only one private window session. Any active tabs / windows maintain that session

Comment: @Phil is correct. You'll need to close all private browsing windows to clear the private session.

Comment: I think you are right, so to prevent storing cookies for a domain when I want to visit it multiple times, I need to open a private window from a normal window each time.